# Record Choice Set Not Recognizing Values

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a record choice set on a Screen element in a flow.  The record choice set worked fine in our sandbox when we only had 3 records to choose from.  Unfortunately, when I move my flow to production, the record choices suddenly don't work.  There should be around 30-40 choices in the record choice set in production.  It has the same criteria that I used in the sandbox. I don't understand why it stopped working.
Someone suggested the issue might be the version of Salesforce that I am on.  I believe I can eliminate that as an issue.  I changed my criteria to just be based off of the contact's last name instead of the two checkboxes I was using originally.  When I did that the record choice set populated.  It just won't work with my checkboxes in production.  The criteria that I want to use are that two checkboxes are marked (one is a flag for employee and one is a flag for faculty).  If both boxes are marked, I want those names to appear in my record choice set.
How can I get this to work?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm if there are any records in production that satisfy your criteria of Last Name and two checkboxes? Record choice sets are nothing but records returned from a query. You can also run a SOQL query in the Developer Console to confirm if you are getting records with all the filter conditions. Maybe there ain't any records with the same criteria in the Production instance.

Comment: I ran a salesforce report with the same criteria and it returned over 40 results.

Comment: I ran an SOQL in the Developer Console with all my criteria.  It returned results.  How can I get the Record Choice Set to populate?  I tried recreating the Record Choice set -- that didn't work.  Our Production Salesforce was just updated this weekend, so I tried re-deploying my Change Set.  That didn't work either.  Record Choice Sets just are not populating in Production.  Is there some permission somewhere that needs to be set for Record Choice Sets to work?